# Hence vs Therefore in casual conversation

Tags: single-word-requests

Trying to be concise, I have been using `hence` instead of `therefore` for some time.
In the context of a casual conversation, **which should be used** (and why)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, depending on the parlance of your peers, either is acceptable as long as they don't look at you funny when you use either word.  You can also use ***"so"***, for example:

> **"I have a headache, therefore I'm not going to class tonight."**
>
> **"I have a headache, hence I'm not going to class tonight."** (this sounds odd to me)
>
> **"I have a headache, so I'm not going to class tonight."**

Comment: "Hence" is far less common as it is indeed unusually old (circa 1200-1300 AD) in its form and use. It generally comes off as ostentatious, and I personally only use it when I wish to be comically fancy. "I do not want to play your silly little game, hence I shall take my ball and go home."

Comment: "Ergo" is clearly the only real option.  *cough*

Comment: @dotsamuelswan: _Ergo_ is a great choice; consequently, I'll upvote your comment.

Comment: Kristina, is "hence" still odd if I, not you, have a headache: "You have a headache, *hence* you shouldn't go to class tonight."

Comment: @Carlo_R., to me it is still odd and old-fashioned sounding.  I think the sentence is a little weird, too, in that under what circumstances would I be saying "You have a headache."  If I change the subject of the new sentence to something less odd, like **"You made me mad, hence, I'm uninviting you to my party."**, **"hence"** sounds a little better but I would still use **"therefore"** or **"so"** before I'd use **"hence"**.